# I lost my phone please help to locate it

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lost-phone

I have lost my phone and I used the Samsung account to locate it, but it didn't work.  Also, I told the police using the IMEI number of the phone.  In the same day I looked into Android Device Manager, but it showed nothing. Even it being stolen on 4/5 and the phone turned on on 8/5 because my friend saw my Viber account once. Can I at least locate the last time my phone was turned on to find my phone?

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking into the Google Location History.  You can access that information by logging into the [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard/) with the google account you had on that phone.  However, I'm not sure if you can activate location history remotely if you didn't already have it enabled.

Comment: Location history is enabled in the Google settings of the device. In other words, it cannot be enabled remotely. However, typically is it on by default.